# Deleting columns if their header contains a certain string

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete columns if the header is `"Column 1"` or `"Column 2"` etc etc.

I am trying to modify the following code so that it adds the "Column x" to the Dictionary and then deletes the column if it contains the words - what i am doing wrong?

```
Sub Macro2()
    Set Dict_Col = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ArrayCol = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)

    ' I'm not sure what to add as a wildcard to the x?
    Dict_Col.Add UCase(Trim("Column x")), 1 

    For i = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 1 Step -1
        If Dict_Col.Exists(UCase(Trim(Cells(1, i).Value))) Then
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you comment your code and tell where it is failing?

Comment: Why do you create a dictionary in the first place? Wouldn't it be simpler to just go through the columns and delete them if their header is `Column X`?

Comment: to slow but i have just solved it

Comment: If you want it faster, use Application.Union on the columns you want to delete.

Comment: How would that be done?

Comment: Your `for` loop cannot work like that. You are deleting columns while you are in the loop.

Comment: @SQLGeorge, You can delete columns in a loop, as long as you loop backwards, as the OP has done. As mentioned by others, it's slower than `Unioning`, but it can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Scripting.Dictionary is completely unnecessary for this task.

1. Go through the header row of the `UsedRange` in a loop
2. Check if the column names have the right format
3. Collect the matching columns in a the `Range` object (via `Application.Union()`)
4. finally delete that Range object in a single step.

Also, think of a nicer name than `Macro2`.

```
Sub Macro2()
    Dim header As Range, toRemove As Range
    Dim parts As Variant

    For Each header In Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows(1).Cells
        parts = Split(header.Value, " ")
        If UBound(parts) = 1 Then
            If parts(0) = "Column" And IsNumeric(parts(1)) Then
                If toRemove Is Nothing Then
                    Set toRemove = header.EntireColumn
                Else
                    Set toRemove = Application.Union(toRemove, header.EntireColumn)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next header

    If toRemove Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Nothing found."
    Else
        toRemove.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

(Untested, I don't have Excel handy at the moment, but the general idea should be apparent.)

Comment: Two main issues with this. 1) After the Split `parts(0)` would be "Column" with no space. The first `Union` will fail because `ToRemove` is nothing.

Comment: Thanks, for proof-reading, both fixed. I should have seen that without testing.

Comment: doesnt appear to work as Object-Variable or With Block variable not set at toRemove.Delete

Comment: @MrAssistance I have fixed the error, now it shows a "nothing found" message instead of an error message. The rest is for you to figure out. Read the code, compare to your workbook and you will see why it does not find the columns you want. I said this code was untested, this implies that you make the necessary modifications.

Comment: Works brilliantly - much better than my attempt

Answer (score 0):

an alternative solution

```
Option Explicit

Sub delcolumns()

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    .Rows(1).Insert
    .Rows(2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Offset(-1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF( COUNTIF(R[+1]C,""Column ?"") + COUNTIF(R[+1]C,""Column ??"") + COUNTIF(R[+1]C,""Column ???"") >0 ,1,"""")"
    .Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Value = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Value
    .Rows(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers).EntireColumn.Delete
    .Rows(1).Delete
End With

End Sub
```

- no iteration
- using a helper row (inserted and deleted before end sub)
- assuming that the number after "Column" can be of 3 digits maximum. if not just adapt the formula

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Macro2()
    Set Dict_Col = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    ArrayCol = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1).Address, Cells(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Address)
Dict_Col.Add UCase(Trim("Column")), 1
For x = 2 To 100

    Dict_Col.Add UCase(Trim("Column" & x)), x
   Next x


    For i = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column To 1 Step -1
        If Dict_Col.Exists(UCase(Trim(Cells(1, i).Value))) Then
            Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no need for a `Dictionary` to delete columns starting whose first row starts with "Column." Also you should qualify your ranges to indicate which worksheet they're on. So although this works for you, I'm downvoting to discrourage others from using this convoluted code.