# HOW TO DELETE COLUMNS USING VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with 12,000 data entries in various columns.
I need to delete all columns with headers that have a "#" in them.
Can anyone advise how I write this code in VBA?
Any assistance will be greatly appreciated as I am relatively new to VBA.

The manual process just takes too long.  I can identify all columns with a "#" in excel but need a formula or function in VBA that can delete these columns with the "#".

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: In this post can get ideas to fulfil the task https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36114386/deleting-columns-if-their-header-contains-a-certain-string.  To find `#` e.g. `if instr(1,"look#for","#")<>0 then `

Comment: As an aside, please don't use all caps (in the title or anywhere else) - it's usually regarded as the equivalent to shouting.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. Commented for explanation.

```
Sub DeleteColumns()

    With ActiveSheet

        'find last used column according to row 1
        last_column = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        'cycle through each column
        For c = last_column To 1 Step -1
        
            'checking first (top) cell in each column for # symbol
            If InStr(.Cells(1, c).Value, "#") > 0 Then
            
                'delete column
                .Cells(1, c).EntireColumn.Delete
                
            End If
            
        Next c
        
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: OP posted nothing but a set of requirements. Not a single line of code/script. No errors. Just requirements. You aren’t answering a programming question; you’re doing free coding-to-spec (not the intent of this site)

Comment: Since deleted, but OP had commented (using an answer, due to low score) on another question which had already provided the bulk of the code. I merely added the IF statement based on Black Cat's comment (and, admittedly, added commentary to aid the OP).